# Working with moodle excellib

Tags: php, excel, moodle

Can anyone provide me with a working example of moodle excellib library. Currently I am unable to use it since it writes the xls file with all the html tags of current page instead of what I really want to write in it. I need to create custom tables using this library. Currently I created an experiment page in /local just to play with it. But had no luck. The code is as follows:

```
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

 //The number of lines in front of config file determine the // hierarchy of files.
  require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/config.php');


  $PAGE->set_context(context_system::instance());
  $PAGE->set_pagelayout('admin');
  $PAGE->set_title("Experiment Page");
  $PAGE->set_heading("Blank page");
  $PAGE->set_url($CFG->wwwroot.'/blank_page.php');


  echo $OUTPUT->header();

  $filename = 'report_'.(time());

  $downloadfilename = clean_filename($filename);
  /// Creating a workbook
  $workbook = new MoodleExcelWorkbook("-");
  /// Sending HTTP headers
  $workbook->send($downloadfilename);
  /// Adding the worksheet
  $myxls = $workbook->add_worksheet($filename);

  $workbook->close();
  exit;

  echo $OUTPUT->footer();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are outputting the page header back to the user's browser, then starting to generate the Excel file. Remove all the $PAGE lines and (most importantly) the echo $OUTPUT->header(); line and it will work much better.

Comment: What if I want the OUTPUT and PAGE variables and at the same time want to write something I like in the file?

Comment: You can either be outputting a file or outputting a webpage, you can't output both at the same time (you can output a page, with a link that will output a file, or with a javascript redirect to output the file).

Comment: I tried the later one, I had a link, that sends the table object to a function defined in another php file which writes it to excel, but it outputs the whole page as well....

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'it sends the table object to a function defined in another PHP file'. The link should point to a PHP file which does just one thing, it outputs the Excel file. If anything else is output in the same request, then the download will not work. There is an example here: https://github.com/davosmith/moodle-grade_checklist . 'index.php' has a form that posts to 'export.php'. 'export.php' does not output anything at all, except for the Excel document.